# Route Component dose not render even though url changes. with custom webpack

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, history, react-dom

[code repository url](https://github.com/shivasai09/PractialTest)

below is my file structure

[image]

and webpack.config.js looks like something like below

```
const path = require("path");

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const entryPoint = path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js");

module.exports = {
  entry: entryPoint,
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
      filename: "./index.html",
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    // publicPath: "/dist/",
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
  },
};
```

i don't know why is it still not working eventhough i have give historyApiFallback

below is my app.js

[image]

when i click on the `/home` route the content is not changing.

could any one please explain me what more i have to add

and my index.js
[image]

Comment: Maybe my question sounds silly but have you wrapped your `App` in `BrowserRouter` ?

Comment: yeah. i have edited the question

Comment: Add ```exact``` prop to each route.

Comment: I think you need to use `render` instead of `component`: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `exact` to your `/` route otherwise it will match anything starting with `/` and since it is in a `Switch` it will be the only one to be matched.

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={() => <div>i am in home</div>} />
      <Route exact path="/home" component={() => <div> i am user</div>} />
    </Switch>
```

If the url is not parameterized, i would add `exact` to `/home` as well

See: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: earlier in react-router-dom v4 it was not needed to add exact to both routes. if would have added to alone home it used to work

Comment: @ShivaSai It is safer to use `exact` if you know you will only need the exact route, so you do not have to debug when you later add a `/home/"id` route. Aslo the order of the Route becomes important when not using `exact`.